# Java HTTPS connection with Custom CipherSuites

Tags: java, ssl, encryption, https

So let's say I try to connect to a web server over HTTPS using HttpsURLConnection. Now if I set/limit the ciphers on Client using:

`System.setProperty("https.cipherSuites", myCustomCipherSuites);`

I want to know how a cipher will be agreed upon between my Java Client and web server. For example, if my cipher suites include [medium, strong] and web server supports [weak, medium, strong, stronger] ...

1- Will "strong" be selected i.e. the strongest available on both client and server?
2- Is there a priority defined by the web server and then an availability check on client to find the cipher with highest priority (on web server) AND mutually available (on both client and server)?

Also, if I have a list of cipher "a", "b", "c", and "d" and web server supports "e", "f", and "g" only ... can I be sure that client and server would both exhaust all possibilities of negotiating a connection with trying to find a common cipher before giving up (as there is not common cipher available). I am pretty sure that answer for this would be yes ... but I just want to confirm it.

Comment: All good questions.  I don't have any answers for you but I did want to point out that you can use the -Djavax.net.debug=ssl Virtual Machine Argument to view your clients ssl handshake with the server.  Hope that helps some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to your first question:

The client offers a list of cipher suites its preferred order (most desired first, least desired last).

The server is *supposed* to choose the first item in the list that it is willing to agree to, ignoring any preference the server may have.  However, there is no (easy) way to prevent a server from using its own preferences (should they not match those of the client).

As to the second, if there is no matching cipher suite, the connection fails.  It's not really an "exhaust", as much as a "I support A, B, C, and D" | "I don't support any of those.  Guess we can't connect."